# How do we run react js production code on local using webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to run my ReactJS production code in local using webpack.
Can anyone check on my setup, please?

webpack.config.js

```
 const path = require('path');
 const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname,'src','index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname,'dist'),
    filename: 'index.bundle.js'
  },
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules']
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname,'src'),
    //host: '00.00.00.0',//your ip address
    port: 4201,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        // we do not want anything from node_modules to be compiled
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [{loader: "html-loader"}]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
          "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
          "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
        ]
      },
      { 
        test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" 
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg|ico)$/,
        loaders: ['file-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname,'src','index.html')
    })
  ]
};
```

when I run npm run build, the process appears to execute correctly (creates build folder, which contains the bundled js file and the index.html file)

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "webpack": "babel-node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack",
    "_start": "babel-node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --open",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.12",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "0.3.0",
    "@coreui/react": "^2.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-config": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",,
    "underscore": "^1.9.1"
  }
}
```

I'm new to react and webpack. I have a very simple react project and tried to run it using webpack in local. But unable to resolve.

Comment: What is the issue exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Try running `NODE_ENV=product yarn start`, I don't know what scripts you have in your `packages.json`, but setting the `NODE_ENV=production` before running the script is what you need

---

**edit:**

In your case, I would change your packages.json. because by default your webpack will run in `development` mode if you don't change the `NODE_ENV`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "webpack": "babel-node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack",
    "_start": "babel-node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server --open",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

Then this `NODE_ENV=product yarn start` will definitely work

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add a script for production mode too as

```
"prod": "webpack-dev-server --mode production",
```

and then
yarn run prod

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can also build the production build using `yarn build` & then deploy locally to test the production.

You can read more about how to test the production build locally at
https://medium.com/@samratshaw/test-react-production-build-locally-434907be9e49